# Binding a TabItem's Header to a property of that tab's Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a WPF application with a `TabControl` in it. In there, I have a `TabItem` containing a custom `UserControl` such as this:

```
<TabItem>
    <local:SomeUserControl/>
</TabItem>
```

I would like to bind the `Header` property of that tab to a property of the `SomeUserControl` element. I've tried simply making a public string property `SomeHeader` in the user control and binding it like this:

```
<TabItem Header="{Binding Content.SomeHeader}">
```

But it didn't work, as the header remained empty when the application was launched. I get the feeling I'm misunderstanding how data binding works here, but I don't know where I went wrong. So, how would I bind this property to the tab's header?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

I needed to set the binding `Path` to `Content.SomeHeader` and `RelativeSource` to `{RelativeSource Self}`, that way the path will look for properties relative to its own object.

```
<TabItem Header="{Binding Path=Content.SomeHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <local:SomeUserControl/>
</TabItem>
```